# How to get the dtypes of all columns in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get list of all columns with it's dtype. How to get this in pandas?

I know I can the result by `print df.info()` 
It will print all the values in console. But I want this to export. How to Get the values like below?

```
{'col1':dtype_of_column_1,'col2':dtype_of_column_2,'col3':dtype_of_column_3,...,'coln':dtype_of_column_n}
```

In other words how to convert result of `df.info()` into pandas dataframe? From Dataframe I can get the required data.

Any Idea would be appreciable.

Comment: Use `df.dtypes.to_dict()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `Series` returned from [`dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7.,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':list('aaabbb')
})

df1 = df.dtypes.to_frame('dtypes')
print (df1)
    dtypes
A   object
B    int64
C  float64
D   object
```

Comment: Yeah Exactly this is what I want :-)

Comment: When I convert into dict values are changing, For Ex `Object` changed to  `dtype('O')`

Comment: @MohamedThasinah - So is necessary converting to string like `df.dtypes.astype(str).to_frame('dtypes')` ?